# TestStack White - Run tests from command line

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, ui-testing, white-framework, teststack

I'm looking for a solution to start my tests from command line.

- I created a UnitTest Procjet in VisualStudio2017 for my .NET solution.
- Added TestStack.White NuGet package to the project.
- The test are running fluently when I start from the VisualStudio2017.
- I would like to start it from Jenkins also. I think it is the easiest to do it from command line, so I add it to my pipeline configuration (Jenkinsfile)

  ```
  stage('Run UI Tests') {
      steps {
          bat('"C:\\PATH_TO_MSTEST\\mstest" /testcontainer:PATH_TO_MY_TEST_PROJECT\\bin\\Debug\\MyTests.dll')
      }
  }
  ```

When I try to start it from cmd like I would do with with regular Unit Tests, it is not working.
It says:

```
Starting execution...  
No tests to execute.
```

I build the project before I start 'Run UI Tests' stage.

**Any ideas how to make it work? Could really find it on stackoverflow, github issues of TestStack nor other glory places on the web**

Comment: Are you trying to run these tests remotely?  I know I had issues with my TFS build related to the computer not accepting UI actions while remote (solved by checking a tickbox that said "UI Tests").

Comment: The Jenkins runs it on an agent. I guess it is remote than. I use the Jenkins with pipeline mode, providing Jenkinsfile, telling the steps to it.

Comment: That sounds pretty much like it should be so far as I know then.  Sorry I can't be more helpful, and good luck.

Comment: Found the solution, just about to answer it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. 
On my local developer machine it was working, the **mstest** version was **14** 
On the build agent machine the **mstest** version was **15**, that was not working somehow (it had nothing to do with TestStack White, simply the unit tests were not working)

What I do is, calling **vstest.console.exe** instead of the **mstest**.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe
```

So, instead of

```
stage('Run UI Tests') {
    steps {
        bat('"C:\\PATH_TO_MSTEST\\mstest" /testcontainer:PATH_TO_MY_TEST_PROJECT\\bin\\Debug\\MyTests.dll')
    }
}
```

My command in the Jenkinsfile was:

```
stage('Run UiTests') {
            steps {
                bat('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\TestAgent\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\TestPlatform\\vstest.console.exe" PATH_TO_MY_TEST_PROJECT\\bin\\Debug\\MyTests.dll')
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

nunit3-console is great alternative to MSTEST. Please refer below link.

e.g.
nunit3-console \bin\Debug\Automation.dll --where "cat=Smoke-Tests"

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line